# API Resources - Call to undefined method ::toArray()

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to change the json return so i am using the API Resources
My route:

```
Route::get('inbox/all', function(){
     $user_id =  Auth::user()->id;
        $inboxtype =   Messages::where('receiver_id', $user_id)->with('sender')->with(['bookings' => function($query) {
                            $query->with('currency');
                        }])->with('item_address')->orderBy('id','desc');

      return new InboxType($inboxtype);

});
```

My InboxType

```
 public function toArray($request)
   {
       return parent::toArray($request);
   }
```

The error

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::toArray()

The line that gives the error is that

```
return parent::toArray($request);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your $inboxtype = .... , it is missing a ->get() . So it should be like this:

```php
$inboxtype =   Messages::where('receiver_id', $user_id)
               ->with('sender')
               ->with(['bookings' => function($query) {
                            $query->with('currency');
                        }])
               ->with('item_address')
               ->orderBy('id','desc')
               ->get();
```

Comment: OMG i am so dumb, i am also tired 9h working plus 4h develop a project :S thanks for your help